# How to convert HD movie from DV tapes from camera

Tags: camera, video-capture, high-definition

I had one party and the camera man just recorded all the videos on mini DV tapes. 
Now he promised me that he will give me `HD 16:9 1080p DVD` for videos

But i am confused how he will convert tapes to HD.
Aren't he has to use HD cameras for that not tapes. or he is lying to me

Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

There are HD cameras that shoot onto mini DV.  Perhaps he has one of those.  If he has shot in SD, then he will probably just upscale the video to HD, and you'll probably notice.  The way to convert these tapes (whether HD or SD) to video is to record them into the computer from the camera and save in some video format (AVI or MPEG, usually).  He might convert them to something with better compression quality, or convert them to DVD.  Just ask him what format the video files will be in, or whether he is going to create a DVD.

Comment: whats the best way to convert from tapes to mp so that quality does not chnage. I saw the sample of that video and quality was not good. i need to tell him which thins to chnage like bit rate etc in capturing software

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that your cameraman knew what he was doing!  If his capture software is converting to MPEG on the fly, then yes: increase the bit rate.  I'm not an expert on video, but it could be that his camera is using HDV to store HD on MiniDV [link](http://www.videomaker.com/article/10618/).  That's an MPEG based format.  Can he just capture 'raw' from the camera?  Perhaps he can get the original quality video off the tape and just burn some DVDs for you.  Then you can mess around with MEncoder or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can Capture HD to Mini DV Tapes. You will then need to import the media from the tapes onto a editing system such as Final Cut or Premiere and then encode it for DVD distribution.